# C# Link to SharePoint Form Library's edit form

Tags: c#, forms, sharepoint, list

I have a task to format some custom search results. I can get the NewForm or EditForm links easily, but if the list is a Form Library they want a link that brings up the form itself and not the list. How do I go about constructing this link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your site is located at "http://sharepoint" and your list is called "FormLibrary" and the form you're trying to display is saved as "MyForm.xml" you would just need to create a hyperlink to "http://sharepoint/FormLibrary/MyForm.xml".